# Symbol not found when dynamic library is moved

Tags: linux, shared-libraries

I have an app that depends on a dynamic library that is not in a system location.  If the library is located in the location from which the executable was linked and LD_LIBRARY_PATH is set to that directory, the application runs.

If the libraries are copied to another directory and LD_LIBRARY_PATH is reset, the application won't start and an undefined symbol error occurs, despite the fact that the symbol appears to be in the library.

Any ideas why this may happen?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Try ldd to show what path used:

```
ldd youprogram
```